# Creating array of file names using grep

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

I'm having difficulty outputting file names as an array using **grep**. Specifically, I want to create an array of file names (plant photos) formatted like this:

```
Ilex_verticillata= Ilex_verticillata1.png, Ilex_verticillata2.png, Ilex_verticillata3.png
Asarum_canadense= Asarum_canadense1.png, Asarum_canadense2.png
Ageratina_altissi= Ageratina_altissi1.png, Ageratina_altissi2.png
```

Here's my original Perl script that I'm attempting to modify. It returns, as intended, ONE file name per plant as "Genus_species", printing a list of those plants:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';
opendir my $dfh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $!";

my @files = 
    map { s/1\.png\z/.png/r } # Removes "1" from end of file names
    grep { /^[^2-9]*\.png\z/i && /_/ } # Finds "Genus_species.png" & "Genus_species1.png" and returns one file name per plant as "Genus_species.png"
    readdir $dfh;

foreach my$file (@files) {
$file =~s/\.png//; # Removes ".png" extension
   print "$file\n"; #Prints list of file names (plant names)
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Ilex_verticillata
Asarum_canadense
Ageratina_altissima
```

However, since each plant often has MULTIPLE photos (e.g.-- "Genus_species1.png, Genus_species2.png, etc.), I need to re-**grep** the directory using the above output to find their file names, then output the results in the form of an array as previously illustrated.

I know the solution likely involves modifying the "foreach" statement, using **grep** to return ALL file names with "Genus_species" in their name. Here's what I tried:

```
foreach my$file (@files) {
$file =~s/\.png//;
   grep ($file,readdir(DIR));
   print "$file = $file\n";
```

But the output was this:

```
Ilex_verticillata = Ilex_verticillata
Asarum_canadense = Asarum_canadense
Ageratina_altissima = Ageratina_altissima
```

Again, I want to output an array formatted as:
"Genus_species= Genus_species1.png, Genus_species2.png, etc.," meaning I want it to look like this:

```
Ilex_verticillata= Ilex_verticillata1.png, Ilex_verticillata2.png, Ilex_verticillata3.png
Asarum_canadense= Asarum_canadense1.png, Asarum_canadense2.png
Ageratina_altissi= Ageratina_altissi1.png, Ageratina_altissi2.png
```

Notice that I also want to add back the ".png" extension ONLY to the file names to the right of the equals sign.

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readdir returns a list of files in the folder. You've put them on one line, which is compact. However, if you loop them you can process the items further.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use English;   ## use names rather than symbols for special varables

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';
opendir my $dfh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $OS_ERROR";
my %genus_species;  ## store matching entries in a hash

for my $file (readdir $dfh)
{
    next unless $file =~ /\d\.png$/;  ## skip entry if not a png file ending with a number
    my $genus = $file =~ s/\d\.png$//r;
    push(@{$genus_species{$genus}}, $file);   ## push to array,the @{} is to cast the single entry to a referance to an list
}

for my $genus (keys %genus_species)
{
    print "$genus = ";
    print "$_ " for sort @{$genus_species{$genus}}; # sort and loop though entries in list referance
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks! I’ll begin experimenting with your code and let you know if this works as intended. I’ll let you know shortly.

Comment: Okay... I just tried your code after inserting the pathway to my directory: "my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';" and get this error: "my" variable $dir masks earlier declaration in same scope". I'm just learning Perl, so I'm probably doing something wrong. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: i thought i'd changed that back..... try as above. The error is because you can only define (my) a variable once, this is due to "use strict" so you dont destroy an existing variable. so i've corrected the definition of my to point to the correct place

Comment: Okay... it working now with your correction! But, it's only listing 299 plant names, rather than 585. I'll have to study the code to figure out why. Also, is it possible to separate the file names with commas? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: But, it's only listing 299 plant names, rather than 585  > check the filenames match the regex " $file =~ /\d\.png$/;" 
Also, is it possible to separate the file names with commas? > change print "$_ "  to match what you need, the $_ each item in the list.

Comment: hoffmeister: I'm very inexperienced with coding...if possible, please post your proposed changes in the code you provided. Regarding the missing plants, I'm at a loss as to why they're missing. I'll try researching the matter further once I decipher " $file =~ /\d\.png$/;. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I recommend the website regex101. Paste all of you file names in there and play with the regex. FYI, the /'s are the delimeters defining the start and end of the pattern. so remove them when checking

Comment: Okay...the entry: "$file =~ /\d\.png$/;  ## skip entry if not a png file ending with a number" is the problem! Yes, I do want to find files ending with the number "1"... but not the numbers 2-9. Also, I want to find files without any numbers, which accounts for the missing files. Additionally, only files with underscores should be returned. Thanks again for all your help!!!

Comment: Simply finding ALL .png files in the directory is sufficient, so I changed "$file =~ /\d\.png$//r;" to  "$file =~ /.png$/;" and now all 585 plants are found. Thank you, hoffmeister, for helping!